# C# Binary Search returning no result

Tags: c#, binary-search

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Get Random Names");
        // Read every line in the file.
        List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("test.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            nameList.Add(line);
        }
    }

        nameList.Sort();
        int startValue = 0;
        int middleValue = (nameList.Count + 1) / 2;
        int endValue = (nameList.Count + 1);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a name to search for.");
        String name = Console.ReadLine();

        bool nameNotFound = true;
        var compareResult = String.Compare(nameList[middleValue], name);


        while (nameNotFound) { 
            if (compareResult < 0) {
              endValue = middleValue;
              middleValue = endValue / 2;
            }
            else if (compareResult > 0) {
              startValue = middleValue;
              middleValue = (endValue - startValue) / 2 + startValue;
            }
            else {
              Console.WriteLine("Name " + name + " was found.");
              nameNotFound = false;
            }
        }
}
}
```

PROBLEM:
I am trying to code a C# binary search that searches a file with a list names (strings). For some reason I can't figure out, the search returns no results. Anyone have any ideas?

SOLUTION:
I've fixed the code now. The two problems were that I wasn't comparing the value in the if and else if loops and I had my greater than and less than symbols mixed up.

Comment: can you provide example data ? maybe there was no result because there was actually no result ;)

Comment: The text file has a list of 20 names. Each name is on a separate line. For example, the 9th name is Marina. When I enter Marina, the program returns no result.

Comment: You are never recalculating your `compareResult` in your last `while` loop. You will be stuck with the compareResult of the first comparison you did before entering the loop.

Comment: You are aware binarysearch is supported on a List?

Answer (score 1):

```
    int startValue = 0;
    int middleValue = (nameList.Count + 1) / 2; // Here you just take the line
                                                // that was in the middle of the file
    int endValue = (nameList.Count + 1);
    // [...]
    var compareResult = String.Compare(nameList[middleValue], name); // and here you check for it
```

.

```
    while (nameNotFound) { // A loop that never compares again
                           // (and makes me wonder how you actually exit the program)
        if (compareResult < 0) {
          endValue = middleValue;
          middleValue = endValue / 2;
        }
        else if (compareResult > 0) {
          startValue = middleValue;
          middleValue = (endValue - startValue) / 2 + startValue;
        }
        else {
          Console.WriteLine("Name " + name + " was found.");
          nameNotFound = false;
        }
    }
```

The TL;DR is that your code provided only ever checks if the most-middle string in your text document is the same as the name provided

you need to compare (again) for starters

Comment: Thanks, I have tried changing that but it still isn't returning a result for any of the names.

Answer (score 1):

In the main algorithm loop at the end, you are never recalculating the `compareResult`, so your program cannot tell when it has found something.

You need to add a `compareResult = String.compare ...` in the `if` and `else if` blocks. .

If you don't do that, `compareResult` will keep the result of the first comparison you did before the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried changing that but it still isn't returning a result for any of the names

Comment: there might be other problems of course. You should use a debugger. go step by step in each line and iteration of your loop, and check that the variables do contain what you think they contain, and that you are actually testing the correct variables. I intentionaly wrote `String.compare ...` instead of the actual correct code, because it's easy to make a mistake here, and there are several possiblities depending on where exactly did you insert the new lines.

Comment: Which software /IDE do you use to program?

Comment: I'm using Repl.it

Comment: I'll try writing some of the variables of the console to see if they're correct.

Comment: Something appears to be up with Repl. It's not updating the any of the values. I'll see if the code works in a different IDE.

Comment: Yes, writing down values with a Console.WriteLine will help a lot. About your last comment, if you're new to programming please take this advice as the most important one : if something odd is showing, don't blame compilers first, always blame your code first (and second, and third etc...) ;)

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it now. Turns out compareResult was returning the opposite of what I was expecting - when I was expecting 1 it was returning -1 and vice versa. I've swapped the greater than and less than symbols in the if and else if and it's working great now.

Answer (score 0):

try to understand the old answers, then try to rewrite enhanced code, if you fail, don't be depressed, look here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
namespace StackOverflowSolver
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Get Random Names");
            // Read every line in the file.
            List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("test.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    nameList.Add(line);
                }
            }

            nameList.Sort();

            //you can get better variables name with replacing Value with Index
            int startValue = 0;
            //int middleValue = (nameList.Count + 1) / 2;   error
            //consider you've three elements, middleValue will be 2 
            //the array index began from 0 remeber that
            int middleValue = nameList.Count / 2;
            //int endValue = (nameList.Count + 1);          error 
            int endValue = nameList.Count-1;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a name to search for.");
            String name = Console.ReadLine();

            bool nameNotFound = true;
            while ((nameNotFound) && (endValue > startValue))//add end search condition
            {
                var compareResult = String.Compare(name, nameList[middleValue]);
                if (compareResult < 0)
                {
                    endValue = middleValue -1; //Substract 1
                    middleValue = endValue / 2;
                }
                else if (compareResult > 0)
                {
                    startValue = middleValue +1; //Add 1
                    middleValue = (endValue - startValue) / 2 + startValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name " + name + " was found.");
                    nameNotFound = false;
                }
            }
            //consider to uncommit the line below
            //Console.WriteLine("Name " + name + " not found!"); //inform not found
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

the code above works well.